# Year() function and Month() function

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, comparison

Good Day Every one Currently im using this codes to get the data that are with in a specific month

```
     SELECT * from Table1  d
where
MONTH(d.fld_ExpiryDate)=@month 
     AND  YEAR(d.fld_ExpiryDate)=@year
```

some of my colleagues told me to use the duration eg.

```
d.fld_LoanDate >= '2009-11-01' and
d.fld_LoanDate < '2009-12-01'
```

the question is would it be better to use the range?? and how would i compute the start of the month and start of next month? if the users input where just `@month int and @year int?`

any help would be greatly appreciated im new in tsql that's why i do not know the work arounds and whats good or not in coding..

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this works on Your locale. It creates a string like "1/9/2013" and converts this to datetime. You could change it and build a string of Your regional convention:

```
declare @y int=2013
,@m int=9
,@lower datetime
,@upper datetime

set @lower=convert(datetime,'1/'+CONVERT(varchar(2),@m)+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(4),@y))
print @lower
set @upper=DATEADD(m,1,@lower)
print @upper
```

This uses dateadd and is propably better, but less transparent:

```
declare @y int=2013
,@m int=9
,@lower datetime
,@upper datetime

select @lower=DATEADD(mm,@m-1,DATEADD(YY,@y-1900,0))
print @lower
select @upper=DATEADD(m,1,@lower)
print @upper
```

(On sql server 2012 You would have [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh213233.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

The range is better if there is an index on `fld_LoanDate`.  The function around the `mont()` and `year()` functions tends to impede the use of the index.

Comment: thank you sir Gordon, any tips on how would i compute the start date and start date of next month? having an input of month and year in INT? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: You would use the `dateadd()` function, perhaps with the day of week as well

Comment: Index will not be used when using the functions, but even without index the range will work faster.